# How to fill the space between two \draw lines

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I am drawing two lines and I need to fill the space between them with a green color. How can I do that in tikz?

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
            \draw (3.1,4.2) -- (2.45,3.8)  (3.1,4.1) -- (2.45,3.7);
    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

I know one way is to draw a green thick line between these two. But I don't want to do that, as it is difficult to align these lines:

```
            \draw (3.1,4.2) -- (2.45,3.8)  (3.1,4.12) -- (2.45,3.72);
            \draw[line width=0.55mm, green] (3.1,4.16) -- (2.45,3.76);
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

using double :

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw[double=green] (3.1,4.2) -- (2.45,3.8);
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw[double=green, double distance=.1cm] (3.1,4.2) -- (2.45,3.8);
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw[double=green, double distance=.2cm] (3.1,4.2) -- (2.45,3.8);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, How can I adjust the thickness of each line? (I am interested in adjusting thickness of the black ones and green one).

Comment: @emab double distance=XX

Answer (score 1):

It is not a perfect solution. The problem are line ends (I made them round, but it is a matter of taste):

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \draw [fill=green, line width=0.mm](3.1,4.2) -- (2.45,3.8) -- (2.45,3.7) -- (3.1,4.1) --cycle;
            \draw[line cap=round] (3.1,4.2) -- (2.45,3.8)  (3.1,4.1) -- (2.45,3.7);

    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You may use `\fill` instead of `\draw` to remove small black lines...